# Rewriting fullscreen in videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I have a HTML5 player using [Videojs](http://www.videojs.com/). I want to rewrite the fullscreen button event to do a different thing.

I have tried rewriting the click event with JQuery and using preventDefault in the way shown below:

```
$('.ico.fullsc').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    // My stuff
});
```

However, besides executing my code, it still does the fullscreen event. Is it possible to do?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can't stop other event handlers from firing in an event handler. `peventDefault` prevents the _default_ action, like changing the url when clicking on a link. `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up. Can you unregister the event properly? Maybe you can put your own button _over_ the fullscreen button.

Comment: @Halcyon thank you for your quick answer. A new button over the fullscreen button could be a solution, but I wonder if it could be done using Javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot that video.js doesn't use jQuery to set up events. My bad!

To do this the way you want to, you're going to have to get a little silly and replace the element with a clone of itself.

```
var fullscreenButton = $('.ico.fullsc').clone();
$('.ico.fullsc').replaceWith(fullscreenButton);
fullscreenButton.on('click', //etc
```

.clone() doesn't pick up event handlers but it does preserve attributes and contents, so you get a stylistically equivalent node but without the event handlers you didn't want.

It's also worth noting that you can go through video.js to add and remove UI elements with your own functionality: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/index.md#customizing

Comment: I also tried unbinding the event, but it still does the fullscreen

Comment: Try using .find('*').off() to get all the children, too. It looks like (from the example player on their home page) that they bind to all of the elements that make up that button for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @Genzotto My bad - the edit should do what you want.

Comment: Perfect answer, save lot of work for the day, Thanks a million. just in default case '.vjs-fullscreen-control' will be in use in place of '.ico.fullsc', Thanks!